# Now, the Arc Welder is not starting test application on Windows

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

Yesterday (10/19/2015 06:00 PM), the ARC Welder app begin to not start apps.

For some reason, now, when I click "TEST", nothing happens on Windows 10, I tested on MAC/Windows 7 also, and works fine.

Chrome
Versão 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit)

ARC Welder
46.5021.478.14

**Update**
This is the error shown on console.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'angle' of
>   undefined
>       at $jscomp.scope.Plugin.computeLayout_ (chrome-extension://joabdphlghkbahegchlcmhbaaijcgghj/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_index.min.js:125:302)
>       at $jscomp.scope.Plugin.doLayout_ (chrome-extension://joabdphlghkbahegchlcmhbaaijcgghj/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_index.min.js:122:383)
>       at $jscomp.scope.Plugin.initializeWindow_ (chrome-extension://joabdphlghkbahegchlcmhbaaijcgghj/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_index.min.js:98:175)
>       at null. (chrome-extension://joabdphlghkbahegchlcmhbaaijcgghj/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_index.min.js:95:238)

Comment: yeah ....it is beta ... you should live with that ... i had tested 46 x86 and x64 ... the canary version (48) ... and no  ... it is not working on windows ... still i'm not sure if it is the best place to ask such question ...

Comment: I tagged google-chrome-arc, as described by google when faced any problem. Why not ask here?  " find us on Stack Overflow (tag: google-chrome-arc) for help."
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

Comment: So this is definitely directly connected to writing a computer program  as in  notice the term "Developer Preview" `The App Runtime for Chrome (Beta), or ARC, lets you run your favorite Android apps on Chrome OS. By following these steps, you can try out the App Runtime for Chrome (Beta) during this Developer Preview.`

Comment: @VansuitaJr. A solution has been added to my answer for ARC Welder  current version 46.5021.478.18_0 but the concept can be applied to any version

Answer (score 3):

## Workaround SOLUTION at bottom.

### **Ok so what I have so far is not a solution just information**

The problem seems to be coming from the runtime part of the Arc Extension:

SEE-> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-runtime-for-chrome-be/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc

The problem is in the file *plugin.js*

```js
// Let the CameraManager in Android know what the current orientation is
  var message = {
    namespace: 'pluginCameraManager',
    command: 'screenRotation',
    data: {
      'angle': screen.orientation.angle
    }
  };
  this.postMessage(message);
```

> Cannot read property **'angle'** of undefined at...

`'angle': screen.orientation.angle`

```js
//for context
var a=Promise.all([this.createAppPlugin_(),window.arcparams.systemDirectoriesReady]);
//problem is initializeWindow_() fails
a.then(function(){this.initializeWindow_();
```

## ** WORK AROUND SOLUTION**

This may cause more bugs, I don't know, do it at own risk.

Open the file:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc\46.5021.478.18_0\gen_index.min.js`

ie

> extension://joabdphlghkbahegchlcmhbaaijcgghj/_modules/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc/gen_index.min.js:125:302)

So on line 125 at character 302 you should find the word 'angle' as in:

`data:{angle:screen.orientation.angle}`

change that to:

`data:{angle:0}`

0 is used,you can read about why -> [Find screen angle when orientation is fixed in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638681/find-screen-angle-when-orientation-is-fixed-in-android#comment38188776_24638681)

Comment: Thanks @CrandellWS, I installed Chrome Beta 47, the property "angle" is there for Windows 7, Windows 10, OSX... All good this way. Only on Windows 8 I have this issue. I talked a little bit with [Mounir Lamouri](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6191285283061760) and the reason is Metro Mode compatibility on Windows 8.

Comment: @VansuitaJr. IT also works  for Version 48.0.2549.0 canary (64-bit) in  Windows 10. https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html Thanks for the bug info

Comment: This bug is still a problem today, your workaround solved it. Thanks! Windows 10 64-bit, Chrome 46

Comment: A [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-runtime-for-chrome-be/mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc) in your answer is now broken, do you happen to know how to access the same data no?

Comment: @Kubuntuer82 I search a bit and found something i can not test as I dont have windows...it suppose to have an archived version of ARC I think https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder-download-and-i/amfcmcnnjljchfmodmhoeocfalipogfe/related?hl=en