# ARC error TypeError Cannot read property 'angle' gen_index.min.js

Tags: google-chrome-arc

- Windows 8 (x64)
- ARC 46.5021.478.18
- App Runtime for Chrome (Beta) 46.5021.478.18
- Chrome 43.0.2357.134 (32-bit)

I was running into the same issue as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240532/now-the-arc-welder-is-not-starting-test-application-on-windows) and the workaround has resolved the issue of the app not launching. I'm curious what the long-term fix would be? I've searched bug reports with no luck. I'm stumped because nothing has changed, ARC, my app, and Chrome versions have not updated since October and the app just quit working a few days ago. I've tried updating Chrome and ARC and still get the angle TypeError.

The manifest file for my app has `"orientation": "portrait"`

I don't use the camera in my app, is there a way to disable the camera in the manifest for the app so it doesn't even run this?

The fix worked on my system but I have ARC and my app deployed to a large number of machines and I'd rather not manually fix them, and some systems are still working fine.

*First time poster, I usually scour the forums and find the answers I need. Your time is appreciated.*

Comment: Don't get it, I have two computers (same platform) running:

 - Chrome 47.0.2526.73 (x64)
 - Arc 47.5021.508.9

Same arc app extension copied to both, one system works one doesn't. I get this isn't supported but basic guidance on what I'm missing or doing wrong would be appreciated.

I wish there were some metadata I could add to tell ARC my device doesn't have a camera. I haven't found anything like that though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short powershell script to put the workaround in place. Not pretty or fancy but it works. I created a shortcut to this script and use it to start the app. This way if ARC updates the script will put the workaround back in place.
Use at your own risk, obviously this could break thing in future updates.

```
#Setting up the variables
$UserPath = $env:LOCALAPPDATA + "\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\mfaihdlpglflfgpfjcifdjdjcckigekc\"
$File = "gen_index.min.js"
$BrokeTxt = "angle:screen.orientation.angle"
$FixedTxt = "angle:0"

#finding the current ARC version
$ARC = $UserPath + (GCI $UserPath | sort -descending | select -f 1)

#Check the file - if broke fix
$FullPath = $ARC + "\" + $File
$CheckFile = Select-String -Path $FullPath -Pattern $BrokeTxt |measure
If ($CheckFile.count -eq 1) 
    {
        (Get-Content $FullPath).replace($BrokeTxt, $FixedTxt) | Set-Content $FullPath
    }

#Open Chrome App
Start-Process chrome -ArgumentList '--enable-nacl --profile-directory=Default --app-id=*APPID*'
```